# Trouble getting getJSON to work with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am trying to use getJSON so I can grab the latest information from my database. What I have done so far is store it into a array and `json_encode(the array)`. That works because I can see the information on the view, but the issue is the ajax method does not pick it up. Maybe i am missing something really stupid.

Controller:

```
public function insertJSON()
{
    $this->load->model("values");
    $queryresults = $this->values->getDb(); 
    $arr = array();

    foreach($queryresults as $row)
    {
        $arr[] =  $row->postcode;
    }

    $data['arr'] = $arr;    
    echo json_encode($arr); 
    $this->load->view('answer', $data);

}
```

View:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    <script>            
        $.post('/localhost/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/insertJSON', function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    </script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Var Dump of the $arr variable:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "test1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "test2."
  [2]=>
  string(5) "test3"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "test4"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the `$data` array (which contains the `$arr`) to the view by calling it ( `$this->load->view('answer', $data);` ) and just right before it you echo the JSON data.

So what you do is call a view which on the top of it, before any html or javascript has a plain text containing the json encoded `$arr`.

This is obviously wrong and not what you are looking for.

You should do either of these options:

1. echo the `$arr` at the view, at the `<head`> section inside `<script>`
   tags. You would not have to use AJAX call though.
2. just echo the
   `$arr` at the controller but do not call a view after it. You should
   probably make another Controller for this. One to echo the `$arr` and
   one to call the View. This way you can do an AJAX call to the first
   Controller.
3. pass the `$arr` to a view which will just echo the JSON encoded data.
   This is like option #2 but it uses the View in order to show the
   data and not the Controller, which is the most appropriate way to follow the MVC pattern.
   Controllers should not echo anything.

I suggest to follow option #3.

Comment: i agree, yet i think he wants it for some kind of live update using ajax.

Comment: thank you sport billy but im looking for a live update just as Momem mentioned

Comment: Then the solution #3 is what you want. It can be implemented for AJAX calls and generally this is the way you should follow for AJAX calls in order to follow the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

So. if you want to echo out a JSON obj that can be pick it up using ajax, then u need to make sure that the output mime-type of your page can serve JSON data.

also notice that u cannt echo anything else with the json data that u want out of ur function. as i can see in your code u echo json then load a view ! u need to split that into 2 separate pages

Fix:

```
public function _JSON()
{
    $this->load->model("values");
    $queryresults = $this->values->getDb();

    $arr = array();

    foreach($queryresults as $row)
    {
       $arr[] =  $row->postcode;
    }

    return $arr;

}


public function json_body(){
    $this->load->view('answer',array('data'=>$this->_JSON()));
}


public function getJSON(){
    $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($this->_JSON()));
}
///note that $this->_JSON() now return ur $arr so u can use it in many methods.
```

now to load page u can go to `/json_body` 'rename it as u want'
and js should be

```
<script>
$.post('<?=base_url('welcome/getJSON')?>', function(data) {
alert(data);
});
</script>
<!--notice that base_url show echo out ur url base on ur config.php file-->
```

NOTE:

function getJson get use the power of CI Output class to set the mime-type of page and make sure this array is the only output. this is not a must but its just best practice. if u want u can relapce all 3 lines with simple `echo json_encode($this->_JSON());` and it will work too !

Comment: thank you very much for the response i am getting an error saying Fatal error: Call to undefined method Welcome::_JSON() in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\welcome.php on line 69

Comment: i called json_body and got this Fatal error: Call to undefined method Welcome::_JSON() in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\welcome.php on line 62 the above is caling getJSON

Comment: figured that out now it displays nothing when i call json_body, but when i call getJSON the information displays the arrays but with the head tag still their

Comment: did you copy all 3 functions that i gave u ? undefined method _JSON() mean that there is no function with that name.. which is strange ! try rename ur functions..

Comment: u shouldnot be calling json_body from anywhere in script, u should view it in ur browser localhost/index.php/welcome/json_body

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is your post URL:

```
$.post('//localhost/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/insertJSON', function(data) {
   alert(data);
 });
```

you missed double slash (//)

Comment: its displaying the source code in the alert for some strange reason thanx

Comment: u cannt echo our the view with the json object, json object must be echoed ALONE with no html other wise javascript will not pick it as an object it will be an html